# OpenGL ES 2.0 2D projection matrix, error converting GLfloat (*)[4] to GLfloat

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I am creating an app in OpenGL ES 2.0 and want to set up a 2D projection matrix to sort out the stretching and distortion caused by the aspect ratio of the screen. I have created a matrix with the required values by using a function. The result of the function is a 4x4 matrix which is then uploaded to the vertex shader. When I run the program I get a build error saying: "cannot convert `GLfloat (*)[4]' to`GLfloat' in return". I have limited C++ knowledge and dont know how to fix this, below is my code of the function I call to.

```
GLfloat ortho_matrix(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near,
float  far)
{
GLfloat result[4][4];

result[0][0] = 2.0 / (right - left);
result[1][0] = 0.0;
result[2][0] = 0.0;
result[3][0] = 0.0;

//Second Column
result[0][1] = 0.0;
result[1][1] = 2.0 / (top - bottom);
result[2][1] = 0.0;
result[3][1] = 0.0;

//Third Column
result[0][2] = 0.0;
result[1][2] = 0.0;
result[2][2] = -2.0 / (far - near);
result[3][2] = 0.0;

//Fourth Column
result[0][3] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
result[1][3] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
result[2][3] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
result[3][3] = 1;

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return a single float from your function, where you need to return a 2D array. Declare your function this way:

```
void ortho_matrix(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near,
float  far, GLfloat result[4][4])
```

Comment: I need the array 'result' to be returned instead of nothing which is implied by the void. What should I replace the void with to make the array return?

Comment: In my prototype you will return the result via ``result`` parameter of the function. You don't need a ``return`` statement and ``result[4][4]`` declaration inside the function.

Comment: I solved it. In the end I stored it as a 1D matrix as the uniform function I was using (glUniformMatrix4fv) automatically made it into to a 2D matrix before importing it to the shader. This then solved the problem of converting from a Glfloat 4x4 to a GLfloat. Thanks for your suggestions and help in getting me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GLM](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/tree/0.9.5/glm). It has proper matrix types and proper support for matrix operations. It is also OpenGL friendly.